# How can I expand a rational expressions of polynomials?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials

I am trying to expand
$$-\frac{2}{(x+2)^3}$$

into
$$-\frac{2}{x^3+6 x^2+12 x+8}$$

How would I do this? Also, How can I extended this to fractions of the form $$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$

where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are polynomials. (so that I expand the numerator and denominator)

Comment: ExpandAll works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `f = -2/(x + 2)^3`. Here are two methods that work:

```
Expand[Numerator@f]/Expand[Denominator@f]
ExpandAll@f
```